# JSP inside ListItems onclick

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to set session parameter inside a list items onclick call such as:

```
<div id="menu"> 
<ul>
    <li class="menuClass" onclick="<% session.setAttribute( "currentPage", "firstPage"); %>">First page</a></li>
    <li class="menuClass" onclick="<% session.setAttribute( "currentPage", "secondPage"); %>"><a href="/index.jsp">Second page</a></li>
</ul>
```

However this results in secondPage being displayed all the time, even without a click. Is this approach even legitimate or is there another way to change session variable and refresh the page within a list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a JSP page is called, the following happens, in this order:

- Server checks to see if the .jsp has already been compiled and whether or not it has changed since it was last compiled.
- Server runs the jsp through the Jasper compiler, which interprets the jsp into Java code, anything that is not Java (CSS, HTML, JavaScript, etc) is placed in a String.
- The Java code is compiled and executed.
- The results are placed in the response and sent to the user.

So, your statement: `session.setAttribute` is executed before the the HTML is sent to the user, and does exactly and `currentPage` is always set to `secondPage` already.

---

How to verify it?

1. add below line before `div` and look what it prints.

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <c:out value="${sessionScope.currentPage }" />
   ```
2. Right click in the browser and look at the view source. There is nothing inside `onclick` attribute because the `setAttribute` was made into a separate command and executed before the page was sent to you.

   ```
   <li class="menuClass" onclick="">
   ```

---

You can try as shown below to pass it as query string instead of session attribute.

```
<a href="/index.jsp?currentPage=firstPage">First Page</a>
<a href="/index.jsp?currentPage=secondPage">Second Page</a>
```

**Note:** Always try to avoid *Scriplet elements* and use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

Comment: Completely neglected how JSP works, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

No, this approach doesn't make sense. You can't expect a JavaScript onclick handler, running in the browser, to execute Java code on the server. The only way for a JavaScript handler to cause changes on the server is to send a HTTP request (using AJAX) to this server.

Remember that everything inside `<% %>` is executed by the JSP engine, on the server, in order to generate the HTML text that is sent as a response to the browser.