# session variable in javascript not updating

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, scope

i am working on two jsp(index and navigation). I am calling some part of html code through ajax on index. I am calling a function "demo()" from navigation.jsp page and defined function in a script within index.jsp page. Here i am setting some variable value in a session variable in navigation.jsp page but when i caught it at index.jsp page it holds the first value. But when i am calling navigation.jsp page, session variable is not updating. Is there any scopr related problem????

```
index.jsp page

     <script>
                    function demo()
                    {
                        var a ='<%= session.getAttribute("ab") %>';
                        alert(a);
                    }<script>

navigation.jsp page

     if(chk1.contains((Integer)value));
        { 
            ch = (String)chk1.get((Integer)value);
            session.setAttribute("ab", ch);
            String bu = (String)session.getAttribute("ab");
            out.println(bu);
        }

    <a onclick="demo()">demo</a>
```

Comment: I am calling some part html code of navigation.jsp to index.jsp through ajax. if i create function "demo()" then it gives error "demo() not define" but when i am defining it in index.jsp , it gives no error but carries only first time value of session variable.

Comment: i am defining function in index and calling through navigation,jsp . Because after ajax call it've been a part of index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

When a JSP page is called, the following happens, in this order:

- Server checks to see if the .jsp has already been compiled and whether or not it has changed since it was last compiled.
- Server runs the jsp through the Jasper compiler, which interprets the jsp into Java code, anything that is not Java (CSS, HTML, JavaScript, etc) is placed in a String.
- The Java code is compiled and executed.
- The results are placed in the response and sent to the user.

So, your statement: `<%= session.getAttribute("ab") %>` is executed before the the HTML is sent to the user, and `var a` is always set to `null` already before calling `demo()` function.

---

For more info have a look at my another post [JSP inside ListItems onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343460/jsp-inside-listitems-onclick/24343789#24343789)

#### How to verify it?

Right click in the browser and look at the view source and look at `demo()` function.

**Note:** Always try to avoid *Scriplet elements* and use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)