# Using Expression language under javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, el

I have below CheckBox in JSP file

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"
    onclick="javascript:selectCustomers(${sessionScope.custId});">
```

Getting the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: customer.jsp(1419,33) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file,
>           attribute onclick does not accept any expressions

Can we not use expression language in JavaScript (in my case under `onClick()` Event)?

Comment: BTW: you can remove `javascript:` as it is just nonsense label in this context - `onclick="anything:selectCustomers();"` works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a JSP page is called, the following happens, in this order:

- Server checks to see if the .jsp has already been compiled and whether or not it has changed since it was last compiled.
- Server runs the jsp through the Jasper compiler, which interprets the jsp into Java code, anything that is not Java (CSS, HTML, JavaScript, etc) is placed in a String.
- The Java code is compiled and executed.
- The results are placed in the response and sent to the user.

So, your statement: `${sessionScope.custId}` is executed before the the HTML is sent to the user, and the input of `selectCustomers()` function is already set to before calling it.

---

For more info have a look at my another post [JSP inside ListItems onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343460/jsp-inside-listitems-onclick/24343789#24343789)

#### How to verify it?

Right click in the browser and look at the view source.

---

Try below sample code that might help you.

Enclose `${...}` inside the single quotes.

```
<c:set var="custId" value="1234" scope="session" />

Before :
<c:out value="${sessionScope.custId}"></c:out>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"
    onclick="javascript:selectCustomers('${sessionScope.custId}');">

<c:set var="custId" value="4321" scope="session" />

After:
<c:out value="${sessionScope.custId}"></c:out>
```

View Source code: (*Right click in browser to view it*)

```
Before : 1234

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"
    onclick="javascript:selectCustomers('1234');">  

After: 4321
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="${sessionScope.custId}">

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" onclick="javascript:selectCustomers();">
```

```js
function selectCustomers(){
   var custId = document.getElementById('custId').value;
}
```