# Can I get a POJO in an Ajax Request to a Spring Controller?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a simple JSP file with some radios, one text input and one button.
In the button onClick I am doing an Ajax request to a Spring controller as you can see bellow:

```js
function callFiltrarViaAJAX() {
   var filtro = $("#filtro").val();
   var optFiltro = $('input[name=optFiltro]:checked').val();

   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "filtrar",
    //dataType : "json",
    data : {
     filtro : filtro,
     optFiltro : optFiltro
    },
    success: function(data) {
                 console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
             },
             error: function(e) {
                 console.log("ERROR: ", e);
             },
             done: function(e) {
                 console.log("DONE");
             }
   });
  }
```

In the Spring controller I am receiving this request with success with the following code:

```
@Controller
public class FiltroController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/filtrar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String filtrarVacina(FiltroTO filtro, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView model) {      
        VacinaTO v = new VacinaTO();
        v.setId(new Long(10));
        v.setLote("Lote 1");
        v.setNome("BCG");       

        model.addObject("vacina", v);

        response.setStatus(200);
        return "TEST OK";
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I'm adding a POJO object in the ModelAndView that I'am trying to use in the JSP to show the return of the Ajax request in a table.
My Ajax request returns with success too but the problem is that even returning with success I can't use the POJO object, when I try to access the object by expression language I got nothing.
I've been searching about this situation and I found a lot of contents but none of the solutions that I've found works for me, but I found an interesting answer:

[JSP inside ListItems onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343460/jsp-inside-listitems-onclick/24343789#24343789)

So, is it means that I can't get a new parameter in the same JSP file with a Ajax request ? If yes, would be a JSON file the better way to get the return from the Spring controller ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the model because you're returning an arbitrary string from controller instead of the view in which you want to access model.

If you're trying to access `vacine` from `some.jsp`, then you should return `some` from the controller method.

Of course, what I said is valid if you have proper `ViewResolver` configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have proper ViewResolver configuration.

I know that I'm returning an arbitrary string from Spring controller to the Ajax request, but how can I return the object ? That is the point. 

I have tried return the ModelAndView to the Ajax request and it didn't work.

My problem is just in the Ajax request, if I add an object in the ModelAndView in a new submit I can access this object with expression language in the JSP file pretty well, but with Ajax request no.